# WCF "global coordinator"

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I'm implementing Web service in C# using WCF. The goal is to create service which gives users ability to write or read files from the server within let say "transaction".
Example scenario for writing:

1. User openes the transaction (send open request to the server)
2. User send request with filename and content to write a file
3. ...other read/write operations...
4. User ends the transaction and changes are made (commited) in the server.

Since it is part of small distributed system that already exists I have to use JSON and send it over HTTP and it cannot be changed.

Transactions are distinguished based on ID generated by the client (UUID). The transaction have limited maximum idle time. When the transaction is opened it exists till the timeout is reached or the transaction is finished by the client. Every new operation within the transaction should reset the timeout counter.
Every time the client wants to write a file, the file is blocked for the time of transaction exists.  If the file is already blocked by other transaction the request waits some time for the file to be opened. If it opens the operation continues, otherwise the whole transaction is rolled back.

I'm using following configuration:

- in order to receive and send JSON I set `binding="webHttpBinding"` for my service endpoint.
- in order to store global data (i.e. about blocked files or opened transactions) and provide servicing for more than one client at the same time I'm using single instance mode and multiple concurrency mode:
  `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]`

My IService.cs:

```
namespace WcfJsonRestService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                   UriTemplate = "/data")]
        Response handleRequest(TransactionRequest tRequest);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class TransactionRequest
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string action { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public RequestData data { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class RequestData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string client_name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string transactionId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string file { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to have something like "global coordinator" / main thread / handler that works all the time in order to manage opened transactions and blocked files. I need following functions to use inside my service:

- add new transaction
- check if transaction of given ID is already opened / exists on opened transaction list
- remove transaction after timeout
- reset timeout counter for a transaction
- plus similarly for blocked files.

I do not know how to implement such coordinator thread/service working in background. It will resolve problem with managing multiple threads inside service class. I thought about another service storing information about transactions , blocked files and their timeouts with funcionality to get or reset them but it will double the communication and lower the reliability of my service.

**Question:** How to introduce a background thread/service managing states of my service like blocked file or opened transactions?

Comment: This is way too broad of a question for Stack Overflow, you've essentially given a long list of requirements and a problem definition, without having asked a question at all.

Comment: Ok. I have edited the last part of my post. Basically the question is - how to introduce a background thread/service managing states of my service like blocked file or opened transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think of the "coordinator" as an agent that runs in the background and manages everything. That agent could be implemented as a thread as you suggest. Requests would come in to that agent, be served and replied to.

It is not necessary to have such an agent/thread. You can perform all the necessary processing on the WCF threads as the requests come in. You need to synchronize access to all shared mutable data structures, of course.

If you simply use a global lock this will be equivalent to the agent-based solution you proposed but simpler.

If you need time-based triggering (maybe for expiration) use a timer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about which timer should I use. Every new client opens new transaction and then the timer is set. So we can have many timers working in the same time. After timer elapsed the transaction should be removed. Should I use `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer`?

Comment: Use `await Task.Delay(...);` to create a simple one-shot timer. (Internally it wraps a timer.)

Comment: Does it allow me to proceed with handling client request and response him without waiting till timer will elapse?

Comment: Yes. Call Delay in a different async method, do the expiry processing after the delay and discard the result task from that async method.

Comment: I have function like this:

`private async Task SetTimeout(string transactionID)
        {
            await Task.Delay(Constants.TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT);
            transactionData.deleteTransaction(transactionID);
        }`


it seems to be working but compiler produces warning: _Warning 1 Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call._

Comment: Google the error to see how to properly suppress it. It's fine. Be sure to handle errors of deleteTransaction, though. If you forget to do that you'll never find out about them and they might be bugs.